# Imported library 'owaspapi' contains no keywords. (if it's installed using pip)

Tags: python-2.7, pip, robotframework, keyword, setuptools

I have made a library for Robot Framework (myapi.py). If I place it in the same directory with my robot test I can import the library like this:

```
Library    myapi.py
```

It works just fine.

However, I made the library pip installable so that others may take it into use in other projects easily. The library installs just fine with pip. I also changed the robot test to import the library like this:

```
Library    myapi
```

When I run the robot test I get warning:

> [ WARN ] Imported library 'myapi' contains no keywords.

Here's the (pip installable) library file structure:

```
setup.py
myapi
  \__init__.py
  \myapi.py
  \version.py
```

The setup.py content is:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

exec(open('myapi/version.py').read())

    setup(
        name='myapi',
        version=__version__,
        packages=['myapi'],
        install_requires=['requests']
    )
```

The **init**.py content is:

```
from .version import __version__
```

The version.py content is:

```
__version__ = '1.1.0'
```

The myapi.py content is (included only the first function I have):

```
import requests
import time
from time import strftime
import urllib2


__all__ = ['create_new_MY_session']

def create_new_MY_session():
    session_name = strftime('my_session_%S_%H_%M_%d_%m_%Y')
    r = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/JSON/core/action/newSession/?zapapiformat=JSON&name=" + session_name + "/'")
    print ("Creating new session: " + session_name + ". Status code...")
    print (r.status_code)
    assert (r.status_code) == 200
```

And finally the beginning of the robot test (login.robot):

```
*** Settings ***

Suite Setup       Open Firefox With Proxy
Suite Teardown    Close Browser

Library           mypapi
Library           OperatingSystem
Library           Selenium2Library

Resource    ws_keywords/product/webui.robot

*** Test Cases ***

MY Start New MY Session
    Create New MY Session
```

I wonder if the library works just fine when located right next to the robot test, what am I missing if I make it pip installable...? Why does it complain that there are no keywords?

Comment: Have you tried opening up an interactive interpreter and then importing your package after it has been installed? Try that, and verify that the thing you imported is a) the installed package, and b) has the function that you think it should have.

Comment: That was a goo idea. Once I tried, I noticed that those did not work in interactive interpreter either. And reason for that came up in @a-kootstra 's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `myapi.py` file you missing the class reference. When the file is placed inside your Robot Framework project this wasn't an issue, but when creating a pip installable module, this is required. A basic Python Library code example is this:

**myapi.py**

```
class myapi(object):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 1.0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def keyword(self):
        pass
```